# What is equivalent to clause between, for comparasion strings in LINQ or lambda expression of?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, razor

How do I filter a query interval of two string using LINQ or Lambda Expression.

example:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Country WHERE Name BETWEEN "Argentina" AND "Jamaica";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
yourDataContext.Country.Where(c => c.Name >= "Argentina" && c.Name <= "Jamaica");
```

Comment: doing so, it asks me the following error:
Operator '<=' can not be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: You have to use `c.Name.CompareTo("Argentina") >= 0 && c.Name.CompareTo("Jamaica") <= 0`, but I'm not sure whether this translates through the entity framework.

Answer (score 23):

perpetrators  >= and <= are not for strings. they will throw compile time error to you. you can use CompareTo for this as shown below

```
x.Name.CompareTo(Start) >= 0 && x.Name.CompareTo(End) <= 0
```

Comment: Works in linq to entities

Answer (score 0):

var query = yourDataContext.Country..Where(Name => Name.IsBetween(Argentina, Jamaica));

Comment: Did you mean to use this with two dots?:  `ntry..Wh`